# SystemV IPC facilities: they have undefined and unpredictible behaviors

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system, ipc

Today I had the OS class exam, and I don't think I succedeed.
The assignment was this:

> Write a program that implements the classical mechanism of readers and
>   writers (with precedence to readers). Use a struct defined this way
>   `struct { unsigned long read_count; unsigned long value};`as shared memory.
>   The main must create n reader processes and m writer processes, where n and m 
>   are passed to main as arguments.
>   Readers will print `value`, while Writers will read it and increment it by one.
>   To guarantee synchronization and mutual exclusion, use two semaphores (`mutex`
>   and `rw_mutex`).

**My professor wrote the SEM_* functions so as to simplify our work**

This is how I did it (D is for debugging purposes).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>


#define SHM_KEY (key_t) 1234        
#define MUTEX_KEY (key_t) 5678      
#define RW_MUTEX_KEY (key_t) 91011  
#define SIZE sizeof(SharedMemory)   
#define MAX_PROCESSES 1000          
#define D                           


typedef struct {
    unsigned long read_count;
    unsigned long value;
} SharedMemory;


int shm_id, mutex, rw_mutex;
SharedMemory *shm;
void *mem_addr;


void reader(void);
void writer(void);


union semun {
    int val;
    struct semid_ds *buf;
    unsigned short *array;
};


int SEM_SET(int sem_id, int sem_num, int sem_val)
{
    union semun sem_union;
    sem_union.val = sem_val;
    if (semctl(sem_id, sem_num, SETVAL, sem_union) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


void SEM_DEL(int sem_id, int sem_num)
{
    union semun sem_union;
    if (semctl(sem_id, sem_num, IPC_RMID, sem_union) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to delete semaphore");
    }
}


int SEM_P(int sem_id, int sem_num)
{
    struct sembuf sem_b;
    sem_b.sem_num = sem_num;
    sem_b.sem_op = -1;
    sem_b.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    if (semop(sem_id, &sem_b, 1) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int SEM_V(int sem_id, int sem_num)
{
    struct sembuf sem_b;
    sem_b.sem_num = sem_num;
    sem_b.sem_op = 1;
    sem_b.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    if (semop(sem_id, &sem_b, 1) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: main <readers> <writers>\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    if (argc == 4) {
        #define D printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
    }

    int val, i, stat_loc;
    int readers = atoi(argv[1]), writers = atoi(argv[2]);
    int n_processes = readers + writers;
    pid_t temp_pid, children[n_processes];

    D;
    shm_id = shmget(SHM_KEY, SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (shm_id == -1) {
        perror("Error creating the shared memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    D;

    D;
    mutex = semget(MUTEX_KEY, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (mutex == -1) {
        perror("Error creating the mutex semaphore");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    D;

    D;
    rw_mutex = semget(MUTEX_KEY, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (rw_mutex == -1) {
        perror("Error creating the rw_mutex semaphore");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    D;

    D;
    mem_addr = shmat(shm_id, (void *) 0, 0);
    if (mem_addr == (void *) -1) {
        perror("Error attaching to the memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    D;

    D;
    shm = (SharedMemory *) mem_addr;
    D;

    D;
    val = SEM_SET(mutex, 0, 1);
    if (val == -1) {
        perror("Error initializing the mutex semaphore");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    D;

    D;
    val = SEM_SET(rw_mutex, 0, 1);
    if (val == -1) {
        perror("Error initializing the rw_mutex semaphore");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    D;

    D;
    for (i = 0; i < readers; i++) {
        temp_pid = fork();
        if (temp_pid == -1) {
            perror("Error creating the process");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (temp_pid != 0) {
            children[i] = temp_pid;
        }
        else {
            reader();
        }
    }
    D;

    D;
    for (; i < n_processes; i++) {
        temp_pid = fork();
        if (temp_pid != 0) {
            children[i] = temp_pid;
        }
        else {
            reader();
        }
    }
    D;

    D;
    for (i = 0; i < n_processes; i++) {
        temp_pid = waitpid(children[i], &stat_loc, 0);
        if (WIFEXITED(stat_loc)) {
            printf("Process with PID %d exited with exit status %d.\n", temp_pid, WEXITSTATUS(stat_loc));
        }
        else {
            printf("Process with PID %d exited abnormally.\n", temp_pid);
        }
    }
    D;

    D;
    val = shmdt(mem_addr);
    if (val == -1) {
        perror("Error detaching from memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    D;

    D;
    val = shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, 0);
    if (val == -1) {
        perror("Error erasing memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    D;

    SEM_DEL(mutex, 0);
    SEM_DEL(rw_mutex, 0);

    printf("Resources unallocated successfully.\n");
    printf("Finished.\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


void reader(void)
{
    int val;
    D;
    val = SEM_P(mutex, 0);
    if (val == -1) {
        perror("P() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    D;
    shm->read_count += 1;
    D;
    if (shm->read_count == 1) {
        D;
        SEM_P(rw_mutex, 0);
        D;
    }
    D;
    printf("Value (PID %d) = %lu.\n", getpid(), shm->value);
    D;
    shm->read_count -= 1;
    D;
    if (shm->read_count == 0) {
        D;
        SEM_V(rw_mutex, 0);
        D;
    }
    D;
    val = SEM_V(mutex, 0);
    if (val == -1) {
        perror("V() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    D;
}


void writer(void)
{
    unsigned long x;
    int val;

    D;
    val = SEM_P(mutex, 0);
    if (val == -1) {
        perror("P() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    D;
    SEM_P(rw_mutex, 0);

    x = shm->value;
    x += 1;
    shm->value = x;
    D;
    SEM_V(rw_mutex, 0);
    D;
    val = SEM_V(mutex, 0);
    if (val == -1) {
        perror("V() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    D;
}
```

A sample run with the program gives me the following error

```
riccardo@riccardo-PC:~/Documents/Programming/OS/Collection/Compito$ ./main 1 1 e106
112
114
120
122
128
130
136
138
140
142
148
150
156
158
172
174
227
233
235
237
184
186
227
```

Or (without the 4th argument)

```
riccardo@riccardo-PC:~/Documents/Programming/OS/Collection/Compito$ ./main 1 1 
106
112
114
120
122
128
130
136
138
140
142
148
150
156
158
172
174
227
233
235
241
Value (PID 10805) = 0.
243
184
245
186
251
257
172
174
227
233
235
241
Value (PID 10806) = 0.
243
245
251
257
184
186
Process with PID -1 exited abnormally.
Process with PID -1 exited abnormally.
184
196
186
198
204
206
212
Failed to delete semaphore: Invalid argument
Resources unallocated successfully.
Finished.
227
P() failed: Invalid argument
Process with PID 10807 exited with exit status 1.
Process with PID -1 exited with exit status 1.
196
198
204
206
212
Failed to delete semaphore: Invalid argument
Failed to delete semaphore: Invalid argument
Resources unallocated successfully.
Finished.
Process with PID 10805 exited with exit status 0.
Process with PID 10806 exited with exit status 0.
196
198
204
206
Error erasing memory: Invalid argument
```

Can you please help me figure out what's wrong. It seems that the we enter the `reader()` function, it somehow stucks.
Thanks.

Comment: [TL;DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR). And please learn how to use a debugger so you will be able to debug it yourself. Or get [a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: If my professor taught us how to debug. He didn't teach us to use a dbg and such. How am I  supposed to use it?

Comment: One of the great things about being a student is learning new things.  One of the things about being a great student is exercising some initiative to learn things for yourself.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you're perfectly right and that's what I do. But, I also believe that system v Ipc facilities need someone who knows what he's doing. And my professor doesn't know that.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: when exiting due to an error, the status certainly is  not `SUCCESS`. so this line: `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` when the wrong number of arguments supplied, should be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the `D;` statements do not compile.  suggest defining a macro: `#define debug  if( 4 == argc ) fprintf( stderr, "%d\n", __LINE__);` and then simply write `debug` where ever you want to output this line  if `argc` is not visible then have main set a variable and have this macro check that variable

Comment: in C, ALL CAPS is normally only used for macro names, not function names.  AND function names should include some active verb, that says what the function does.  Similarly variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).

Comment: regarding: printf("Usage: main <readers> <writers>\n"); 1) error messages should be output to stderr, using something like: fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s <readers> <writers>\n", argv[0] );  And this statement is missing the optional (usually delimited by `[` and `]` ) 4 the parameter

Comment: when including header files, do NOT include header files those content is not used in the current file.  For instance the contents of the header file `errno.h` are not used so that header file should not be used.

Comment: the `fork()` function has three different return indications: 1) <0 means failure 2) =0 means child process executing 3) >0 means parent process executing.

Comment: some resources, like semaphore, IPCs, etc result in entries in the `/proc/` file structure.  If the program exits without first cleaning up (by deleting those items) then the next time the program is run, those items will already exist and trying to create them (again) will result in errors.  So when exiting the program, due to errors, those resources must be eliminated before exiting. (I.E. the OS will not delete them for you.)

Comment: the `reader()`  process, (all to easily confused with the variable `readers`) does not properly exit for all paths through the code, so can return to the `main()` and start executing the rest of `main()` after the call to the `reader()` process.  Similar statements apply to the `writer()` process

Comment: strongly suggest using one of the `exec*()` functions to execute the `reader` and `writer` processes.